# How to draw "wavy" sequence of boxes

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-shape

I'm very new to TikZ and I'm having a slight problem that I'm not entirely sure how to solve.

Suppose I generate a sequence of boxes like so:

```
 \documentclass{report}
 \usepackage{tikz}

 \begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
 \foreach \x in {1,2,...,5}{
      \draw (\x,0) -- (\x+1,0) -- (\x+1,1) -- (\x,1) -- cycle;
 }
 \end{tikzpicture}
 \end{document}
```

How can I introduce a "wavy" effect to the sequence such the the boxes fit within the following shape:

```
 \documentclass{report}
 \usepackage{tikz}

 \begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
 \draw (0,0) .. controls (2.5,0.5) and (7.5,-0.5) .. (10,0) -- (10,1) .. controls (7.5,0.5) and (2.5,1.5) .. (0,1) -- cycle;
 \end{tikzpicture}
 \end{document}
```

I also want to colour these boxes using `fill=`, so I need for them to be recognised independent entities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know the curve of your wave, you can use the `plot` command from `tikz`.  I assume that it is not essential to use the spline that you gave in your MWE, so I replaced it with a sine wave that looks similar:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \foreach \x in {1,2,...,5} {
    \draw (\x,0) .. controls (\x+0.25,0.5) and (\x+0.75,-0.5) .. (\x+1,0) -- (\x+1,1)  .. controls (\x+0.75,0.5) and (\x+0.25,1.5) .. (\x,1) -- cycle;
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image: a sine wave]

Then, one just has to use the same function to plot the boxes:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[domain=0:10] (0,0) -- plot (\x,{0.2*sin(\x*36)}) -- plot (10-\x,{1-0.2*sin(\x*36)}) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image: a wave of boxes]